# PDO concatenating SQL Query with placeholders

Tags: php, pdo

I'm in the process of converting my mysql_.* functions to PDO. Prior to this, I would build my query by concatenating it based on other factors. Here's an example:

```
class carriersInfo
{

    protected $start_date;
    protected $end_date;
    protected $data = array();
    public function __construct($start = 0, $end = 0)
    {
        $this->start_date = $start;
        $this->end_date = $end;
        $this->topCarrier();
    }

    protected function buildQ()
    {
        $sql =  "SELECT `shipped_by`, COUNT(`shipped_by`) AS `total` FROM `deliveries` ";
        if($this->start_date!=0 and $this->end_date!=0)
        {
            $sql .= " WHERE ship_date>='".$this->start_date."' AND ship_date<='".$this->end_date."' ";
        }   
        $sql .= " GROUP BY `shipped_by` ";
        $sql .= " ORDER BY total ASC "; 
        return $sql;    
    }

    public function topCarrier()
    {       
        $query = $this->buildQ();
        $SQL = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($SQL))
        {
            $this->data[$data['shipped_by']] = $data['total'];
        }
        return $this->data;
    }   
}
```

The SQL query was build depending if the user chose to specify a date range. How can I  achieve the same effect using PDO prepared statements and nameplaceholders?

**Attempt**

```
class carriersInfo
{

    protected $start_date;
    protected $end_date;
    protected $data = array();
    protected $_INSTANCE;
    public function __construct($start = 0, $end = 0)
    {
        $this->_INSTANCE = Core::getInstance();
        $this->start_date = $start;
        $this->end_date = $end;
        $this->topCarrier();
    }

    protected function buildQ()
    {
        $sql =  "SELECT `shipped_by`, COUNT(`shipped_by`) AS `total` FROM `deliveries` ";

        if($this->start_date!=0 and $this->end_date!=0)
        {
            $sql .= " WHERE ship_date>=:start_date AND ship_date<=:end_date ";
        }   
        $sql .= " GROUP BY `shipped_by` ";
        $sql .= " ORDER BY total ASC "; 



        return $sql;    
    }

    public function topCarrier()
    {       
        $Q = $this->buildQ();
        $query = $this->_INSTANCE->pdo->prepare($Q);
        $query->bindValue(":start_date",$this->start_date);
        $query->bindValue(":end_date",$this->end_date);
        $query->execute();  

        while($data = $query->fetch())
        {
            $this->data[$data['shipped_by']] = $data['total'];
        }
        return $this->data;
    }   
}
```

The binding parameters won't work in this case if the user did not enter a date range and would cause an error.

Comment: So, you are basically asking us to change a `Mysql` query to `pdo`? is that it?

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself yet?

Comment: Let me post my attempt.

Comment: @Dimitri - you're checking in `buildQ()` if you have a start date, and if so, adding the WHERE clause. You can use the same logic in `topCarrier()`, too, and only bind the parameters if you have a start date.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, attempting to bind parameters that don't exist is causing your query to fail. Based on that, you should just add a check for those properties:

```
public function topCarrier()
{       
    $Q = $this->buildQ();
    $query = $this->_INSTANCE->pdo->prepare($Q);
    if($this->start_date!=0 and $this->end_date!=0) {
        $query->bindValue(":start_date",$this->start_date);
        $query->bindValue(":end_date",$this->end_date);
    }
    $query->execute();  

    while($data = $query->fetch())
    {
        $this->data[$data['shipped_by']] = $data['total'];
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean you're evaluating the start and end dates twice? Once in the buildQ method and once in the topCarrier?

Comment: You're evaluating it once when you're building the query and again when you're binding parameters. You could replace that with just a single boolean value, but I don't know that it saves you much to do so.

Comment: Yea, my biggest issue is that the buildQ method has almost 20 sorts of evaluations prior to building the query. The one I posted is just a simplified version of it. I was trying to find a logical way to build my query with the prepare and bind parameters. What's causing the issue is placing the bindValue appropriately. Unless I go old school and throw the actual variable in the statement with no placeholders..

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Didn't know you can execute an array of parameters. Here's my solution.

```
class carriersInfo
{

    protected $start_date;
    protected $end_date;
    protected $data = array();
    protected $_INSTANCE;
    protected $_PARAMETERS = array();

    public function __construct($start = 0, $end = 0)
    {
        $this->_INSTANCE = Core::getInstance();
        $this->start_date = $start;
        $this->end_date = $end;
        $this->topCarrier();
    }

    protected function buildQ()
    {
        $sql =  "SELECT `shipped_by`, COUNT(`shipped_by`) AS `total` FROM `deliveries` ";

        if($this->start_date!=0 and $this->end_date!=0)
        {

            $sql .= " WHERE ship_date>=:start_date AND ship_date<=:end_date ";
            $this->_PARAMETERS[":start_date"] = $this->start_date;
            $this->_PARAMETERS[":end_date"] = $this->end_date;
        }   
        $sql .= " GROUP BY `shipped_by` ";
        $sql .= " ORDER BY total ASC "; 
        return $sql;    
    }

    public function topCarrier()
    {       
        $Q = $this->buildQ();
        $query = $this->_INSTANCE->pdo->prepare($Q);
        $query->execute($this->_PARAMETERS);    

        while($data = $query->fetch())
        {
            $this->data[$data['shipped_by']] = $data['total'];
        }
        return $this->data;
    }   
}
```